# Android configuration in Qt Creator

Tags: android, qt, sdk, android-ndk, qml

Any idea of how to solve these issues related with the Android configuration in Qt Creator?

Please look at this image below to see the issues:
[Android configuration issues in Qt Creator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/st4Hu.png)

I installed all the Android SDK and NDK tools from the Android SDK Manager included in Android Studio in Windows 11. And now I need to configure the Android SDK and NDK in Qt Creator. The Java configuration is done. I am using Qt 6.5.1 for Android
[List of Qt installed versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLnqa.png)

Comment: Android development is fussy; your JDK, SDK and NDK all need to "agree" with each other. I think you need a newer JDK (I'm using 11.0.17.8).